# What is the meaning of "бавовна" (cotton) referring to explosions?

Tags: non-native-speaker, сленг

Recently, Ukrainian news and social media began to use the word *бавовна* (cotton) to refer explosions on russia and its military settlements:

- ["Бавовна" в Криму: в мережі з'явилося відео з наслідками вибуху](https://www.5.ua/regiony/bavovna-v-krymu-v-merezhi-ziavylosia-video-z-naslidkamy-vybukhu-284552.html)
- [Ранкова "бавовна": у російському Єйську за 30 км від Маріуполя палає нафтобаза](https://www.5.ua/svit/rankova-bavovna-u-rosiiskomu-yeisku-za-30-km-vid-mariupolia-palaie-naftobaza-video-284574.html)
- ["Бавовна" несподівано спіткала білорусь: у мережі пишуть про вибухи на аеродромі під Гомелем](https://24tv.ua/bavovna-nespodivano-spitkala-bilorus-merezhi-pishut-pro-vibuhi_n2121884)

What is the importance of this term and its origin?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Бавовна* `/bavóvna/` is a recently-introduced meme about the current russo-Ukrainian war (2014-current). It is, indeed, a linguistic phenomenon.

There are three factors at play here:

1. Throughout recent years, russian propaganda uses various euphemisms and [newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak) to diminish the importance of catastrophic events in its controlled territories: terms like "newly available manpower" for "rise in unemployment", "water-soaking" for "flood", "a negative rise of the economic growth" for "economic decline", etc. One of the most used terms is ***хлопо́к*** (/xlopók/ - clap, pop) for "explosion".
   The Ukrainian word for "clap" is also ***хлопо́к***; note the stress on the 2nd syllable.
2. The word ***хло́пок*** (/xlópok/ - cotton) has the same spelling, except it has stress on the 1st syllable.
   The Ukrainian word for "cotton" is ***бавовна***.
3. Like everywhere, russian Internet trolls continue the information war on Ukrainian social media. Most of them do not speak Ukrainian, but they pretend as Ukrainians in order to deceive Ukrainians. They use **machine translation** from russian to Ukrainian, which leads to the following kind of posts:

   [image: bavovna]

   *Слышен мощный хлопок* <sub>rus</sub> - a severe **clap** was heard;
   *Чулася потужна бавовна* <sup>ukr</sup> - a severe **cotton** was heard.

Once appeared, this word became a meme from there on and began its own evolution in Ukrainian social networks and on public news agencies to denote explosions on russian military bases and on the front line.

In her [speech](https://twitter.com/ukinukraine/status/1562305061845405696) on Ukraine's Independence Day, British Ambassador to Ukraine Melinda Simmons appeared with a bouquet of sunflowers and bavovna flowers:

[image: British Ambassador to Ukraine Melinda Simmons with a bouquet of bavovna flowers]

Additionally, the visual appearance of a cotton flower resembles an explosion, so modern AI (Artificial Intellect) engines, when asked for [*бавовна на курорті*](https://twitter.com/OstapYarysh/status/1557708711107469312) (cotton on a beach), draw pictures like this:

[image: a cotton on a beach 1] [image: cotton on a beach 2]

---

Sources:

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0#Etymology_2)
- [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bavovna)

Comment: Any chance there could be an older connection? Reason I am asking: In older German military slang there is a phrase of unknown origin: "Kattun kriegen" (to get *Kattun*) which means to come under heavy fire. *Kattun* is cognate with English "cotton" and refers to a kind of cotton fabric, I think calico. In an example sentence from E. M. Remarque's "All Quiet on the Western Front" (about WW1) is seems to refer specifically to intense artillery bombardment: "Kat horcht hinaus: »Diese Nacht gibt es Kattun.«". Personal speculation: phrase could have originated with use of guncotton in 19th cent.

Comment: @njuffa Combining https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Soldatensprache#K and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/S#Sie_sagen_Christus_und_meinen_Kattun. (in both links, you need to search the page for Kattun): "Kattun" could refer to cleaning cloth of english origin, therefore "Kattun kriegen" could have started as an euphemism for "we'll be cleaned off by the tommies". But that's a question for the german SE, I notice that there's no search result there for "Kattun" yet ;-)

Comment: And there was a huge rush with russian homonyms having different semantical equivalents in ukrainian - `Підлога країни хоче змінити державний будуй, бо нема вже сечі терпіти ці борошна.` That was an infallible sign of russians intended to mimic ukrainians by google translate.

Comment: Why `/xlopok/` instead of `/hlopok/`? The first one is pronounced as `KSLopok`

Comment: @stkuser [because](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/301/1009) slashes represent the *broad* transcription intended for illustration purposes, contrary to a more specific phonology-based transcription you might have seen with IPA.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that cotton is used in production of explosives (e.g. Nitrocellulose), which is a coincidence that amplifies the meme