# Чому слова "протестовать" и "протестировать" з російської мови перекладаються на українську як "протестувати"?

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова

Маю питання, як в українській мові відрізняти значення слова **протестувати** також, як в російській мові *протестовать* від *протестировать*.

Comment: _"Як в українській мові відрізняти значення слова протестувати?"_. Я особисто щоб відрізнити інколи вживаю слово _"відтестувати"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ніяк.

В усіх мовах деякі словоформи збігаються, письмово та/або фонетично:

- Сучасна англійська має безліч слів, дієслівна, прикметникова і іменникова форми яких збігаються. Той же *test* може бути як дієсловом, так і іменником або прикметником.
  Іноді така неоднозначність приймає гротескні форми: [Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana)
- На відміну від інших мов, як-то німецьке *protest**ier**en* — це винятково дієслово.
  До речі, німецький суфікс `-ier-` і є «винуватцем» відмінностей між *протестовать* та *протестировать*
- Московський язик не відрізняє між собою слова *половина*, *підлога* і *стать* (у них це *«пол»*) або *любов* і *кохання*, а з фонетичної точки зору, значна кількість мовців плутаються в написанні **усіх** дієслів з суфіксами `-тся` та `-ться`.
  Тут же криється і нескінченне джерело жартів про *підлога країни, пекельні борошна* і навіть про [*бавовну на аеродромі*](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6983/8).
- Сучасна китайська фонетика [взагалі має](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/40574/752) 1274 фундаментально різні склади (враховуючи чотири різні тони).

Тобто, це типова проблема, і вирішення її також типове:

- мовець намагається **уточнити контекст** або **використати синонім**, щоб уникнути неоднозначності,
- а слухач обирає серед можливих значень те, яке відповідає **контексту**.

---

## Чтиво

- [How do natural languages prevent word ambiguity in "compound words"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/43582/1009) — **це буквально ваше запитання**, тільки в більш широкому контексті різних мов;
- [How is "Writer/reader-responsible language" correlated with synthetic/analytic languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8962/1009)
- [Whispering in languages heavily dependent on pitch or phonation distinctions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29914/1009)